# How to show that $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ does not have a Taylor-Maclaurin expansion

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

I know that $x\neq0 \Rightarrow f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}},f(0)=0$ does not have a *good* Taylor-Maclaurin expansion
(By *good* I mean that the this expansion is not eonverging to $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$) since all of its derivatives are $f^{(n)}(x)|_{x=0} = 0$.

But, I want to show it by showing that the [lagrange remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html) is not converging to $0$. How can I do that. I mean, isn't the lagrange remainder always $0$ in this case and therefore also converges to $0$?

Thanks

Comment: Note the "for some $x^*\in(x_0,x)$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrange remainder is not $0$, because the remainder $R_n$ is, by definition, equal to $$R_n = f(x) - P_n(x)$$

where $P_n(x)$ is the $n$-th degree Maclauring polynomial for $f$. Note that $P_n(x)$ is equal to a very simple expression for all values of $n$, which should make $R_n$ easy to calculate.

---

Now, of course one way to calculate $R_n$ is by using the formula

$$R_n = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(x^*)}{(n+1)!}\cdot (x-x_0)^{n+1}$$

however this formula is true **for some $x^*\in(x_0, x)$** so I wouldn't suggest using this here. Much easier to actually calculate $R_n$.